# Sieve rule for search body

Tags: sieve-rules

I am using Protonmail and I am looking for a Sieve rule example. I want to add a Sieve filter rule that if a message was from `x@x.com` and the message body contains "this is the body" then move it to filter "Test1".

I have searched example but could not find a good one, so i will appreciate if I can have a example for this.

Comment: What do you mean by *'move it to filter "Test1"'?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
require ["fileinto", "body"];
if allof(address :is "From" "x@x.com", body :contains  "this is the body") { fileinto "Test1"; }
```

Tested at https://www.fastmail.com/cgi-bin/sievetest.pl with the following test data.

```
From: some person <x@x.com>
To: another guy <you@example.com>
Subject: this is not the body

This is a test, where this is the body and some other text.
```

My understanding is that Sieve extensions are site-dependent; I haven't explored whether Protonmail supports these precise extensions. In fact, their [Sieve page](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/sieve-advanced-custom-filters/#supported-actions-tests) does not mention [the `"body"` extension (RFC 5173)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5173), so maybe it's not available.

Comment: protonmail sieve guide is available @https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/sieve-advanced-custom-filters/ but i did not find body extension, and also protonmail sieve shows error to me when i use body extension

Comment: So then they simply don't support examining the body. If they decide to support it one day, this is what the code would look like. (That's the same page I link to in the answer.)